# The specified SD image file must be a valid image file

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I've been following the setup guide for flutter on https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows. I am at the "Set up the Android emulator" step. I've followed the instructions but I am unable to run the emulator that I set up. When I click on the run option I get the following error:

[image: AVD manager emulator process was killed.]

I've read that this might be due to the Android Studio trying to allocate a space larger than the available size. In order to confirm this, I clicked the "Edit this AVD" option in the "Android Virtual Device Manager".

[image: edit this avd]

Then, I saw that this configuration was trying to use 6144 MB when I had only 4.02 GB available on my C drive (my D drive has more than 800 GB of space but I don't know how to tell Android Studio to use it instead). I attempted to change this to 2000 MB but the program doesn't let me save the configuration due to this error, "The specified SD image file must be a valid image file":

[image: sd image error]

I don't know how to get rid of this. Can someone help?

Edit: After changing my hard drive to a 1 TB one and redoing the setup process for the flutter following https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows, I was able to solve the problem. So, it seems that as Swaminathan V mentioned, there must be available space in C: no matter what. From what I've read, upwards of 7 GB seems to work for the most people.

Comment: check my answer. Which will be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **To use the external image you need to create a new image with the**
> **`mksdcard` tool available with the Android SDK.**

Follow the below steps to generate and use it in the AVD.

Open the `tools` directory under Android SDK directory (`android-sdk`) in `cmd` or `powershell` or `terminal`.

```
<<PATH TO ANDROID ROOT DIRECTORY>>\tools>_     // Example : C:\android-sdk\tools>
```

Then execute the following command to create a image for SD card with desired size.

Syntax : **`mksdcard size destinationFile`**

Example : **`C:\android-sdk\tools> mksdcard 4096M D:\sample.img`**

**The above command will create a image file of size 4GB under the D drive.**

[image]

Now use it in your emulator config.

[image]

**NOTE** : The size should be mentioned in MB. Minimum allowed size is 9MB and Max allowed size is 1023 GB. Please refer [Android official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/mksdcard.html) for more details.

Comment: When I try to create an image file using `mksdcard` at `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools>`, I get the following error: `mksdcard : The term 'mksdcard' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mksdcard
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mksdcard:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: Please try running the cmd in Admin mode. And also make sure `mksdcard.exe` is available under SDK->tools. Otherwise please install them using the Android Studio SDK manager.

Comment: I was able to create an SD image with a size of 8 GB and change the internal storage to 1024 MB. However, I still get the "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 was killed." error. Is there a way to learn what's actually causing this?

Comment: Try updating the Emulator version in the Android Studio and check.

Comment: Tried updating but still the error persists.

Comment: If you have low disk space (C:) also this error will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, with same error message "The specified SD image file must be a valid image file". It appeared when I moved AVD folders to external location on a different drive (due to low space on C:)
Tried creating external image with "mksdcard" tool but got same error outcome as you've written in reply above.
What helped was simply choosing external storage of sd card in configuration. Step by step:

1. Choose pen icon "Edit this AVD" of your desired avd.
2. "Show advanced settings"
3. In section "Memory and Storage", if this error persist, in option SD card choose "external file" and choose directory to **sdcar.img** inside your desired AVD folder.